# python last row recursive pascal triangle

Tags: python, recursion, pascals-triangle

I have to create a recursive function `pascal(n)` that returns the line `n` of a pascal triangle as a list (so `pascal(3)` returns `[1, 3, 3, 1]`).

So far I have

```
def pascal(n):

    if n==1: 
        return [[1]]
    else:
        result=pascal(n-1)
        row=[1]
        last_row=result[-1]
        for i in range(len(last_row)-1):
            row.append(last_row[i]+last_row[i+1])
        row+=[1]
        result.append(row)
        return row
```

But this results in the error

> object of type 'int' has no len()

If i instead write

```
def pascal(n):

    if n==1: 
        return [[1]]
    else:
        result=pascal(n-1)
        row=[1]
        last_row=result[-1]
        for i in range(len(last_row)-1):
            row.append(last_row[i]+last_row[i+1])
        row+=[1]
        result.append(row)
        return result
```

And then call `pascal(3)[-1]`, there is no problem. How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `pascal(n)` to return the nth line of the Pascals triangle as a list, but you are returning [[1]] instead of [1] for `pascal(1)`.

Also, the "last_row", i.e the previous row corresponding to pascal(n) would be `pascal(n-1)` and not `pascal(n-1)[-1]`. In your code, `result[-1]` is `pascal(n-1)[-1]` which the last element (int) of the (n-1)th row, hence the error.

This would be your function after making the above 2 changes.

```
def pascal(n):
    if n == 0: 
        return [1]
    else:
        last_row = pascal(n-1)
        row = [1]
        for i in range(len(last_row)-1):
            row.append(last_row[i]+last_row[i+1])
        row += [1]
        return row
```